# Clone instead of move in jquery ui and angular js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

Currently I am working on a project with `angular Js`. I am creating two div with drag and drop

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucerturohit/zHZxp/)

What I need is that when I drag a div into another then it should clone intead of move. means the drag and drop element should remain in both divs. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your drop function :

```
$(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zHZxp/1/

Comment: @lord_linus : you're welcome! I have had the same issue some time ago too :-)

Comment: Hey can you please help me with the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588394/unable-to-drag-and-drop-with-angular-js