# Unable to drag and drop with angular js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am newbie to `angularjs`. currently I am working with a project for `drag and drop` but with pure jquery ui I am able to `drag and drop` but whenever I am going to include this with angularjs then I am unable to `drag`

Here is the [jsfiddle for what I have done](http://jsfiddle.net/ucerturohit/zHZxp/2/)

How can I inclucde with `jquery ui` with `angularjs`

Update :

Here is the jsfiddle for drag and drop with pure jquery ui

http://jsfiddle.net/ucerturohit/zHZxp/

Comment: I have had a look at your code. First point, when you are using angularjs with jsFiddle, you should choose option "no wrap - in head" in the first option bloc (Framework and extensions). And then, it gives you such code : http://jsfiddle.net/zHZxp/3/. But it still does not work since you call incorrect urls (test.php, ... which are relative -> you should give real ones).

Comment: Sorry for all that actually the problem was that whenever we load data dynamically then we have compile the data

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra library to make drag and drop work with angular js. There are many available on the internet. But What I would personally recommend is this one :

## [Drag and Drop for AngularJS](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/)

examples :

- http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/list
- http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/mvc